# How to disable margin (+/!)?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, highlight

Currently I installed vim addons for python. 
http://fisadev.github.io/fisa-vim-config/

However, I don't like the +/-/! on the margin. Does anyone know how to disable all of them?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: These are called signs, but the real answer is—dont install a big vim config put together by someone else! Make your own!

Comment: Remove `Plug 'mhinz/vim-signify'`. In general, do only install plugins if you know what they are for and you are sure you need that feature.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It works! Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off the signcolumn:

```
set signcolumn=no
```

Comment: should be `:set signcolumn=no`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thanks; i knew it was slightly different from foldcolumn.